# Extend from a specific class while implementing shared methods

Tags: java, android

I'd like to have two classes:  Layout1 and Layout2.  Both will extend a specific class, Layout1 will extend LayoutGroup1 and Layout2 will extend LayoutGroup2.

However, they will both have some common code in the form of a function named doSpecialLayout().

Ideally, I'd be able to have each class extend their appropriate class, and also put the shared doSpecialLayout() code in a common place that both can access.  This will make it cleaner on my end, as well as improve my ability to bug fix stuff later on since I won't be editing two classes each time!

Is something like this possible?  I know I cannot extend multiple classes in Java, so what's the pattern I am looking for here?

Thank you very much!

FYI This is for Java on Android systems, so only Java 6 (7?) is supported.

Comment: Can't you use a common parent class for LayoutGroup1 and LayoutGroup2?

Comment: Take a look at the interfaces with default methods in Java 8.

Comment: LayoutGroup1 and LayoutGroup2 already need different parent classes though.  They are both TYPES of layouts, but not common layout types, if that makes sense.

Comment: I will take a look at interfaces/default methods, thanks for the suggestion. FYI this is for Android work, so I do not think they support Java 8 yet, but would still be good to check this out.

Comment: You can achive same effect as default inteface methods with groovy traits, but thats only for Your information, question is java related.

Answer (score 1):

With `Java 8` you can easily achieve this using `interfaces` rather than `abstract classes`.
Define an `interface` with a `default` method which will hold the common functionality.

```
interface someInterface
{
    default void doSpecialLayout(){System.out.println("Hello");}
}

class LayoutGroup1 
{

}
class LayoutGroup2
{

}
class  Layout1 extends LayoutGroup1 implements someInterface
{
    void someFunction()
    {
       doSpecialLayout();
    }
}

class Layout2 extends LayoutGroup1 implements someInterface
{
    void someFunction()
    {
      doSpecialLayout();
    }
}
```

And in `Java 6:`, simply make use of an `parent class.`

```
class someclass
{
    void doSpecialLayout(){System.out.println("Hello");}
}

class LayoutGroup1 extends someclass
{

}
class LayoutGroup2 extends someclass
{

}
class  Layout1 extends LayoutGroup1 
{
    void someFunction()
    {
        doSpecialLayout();
    }
}

class Layout2 extends LayoutGroup1 
{
    void someFunction()
    {
        doSpecialLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in the comment, but didn't publish as an answer :)

Comment: I was about to suggest this too, hopefully I refreshed the page. In addition to your answer we could add for "educational" purposes that what the OP is trying to do sounds like a [trait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) or a mixin. The "import some kind of common behaviour from another class" often implies using a trait. We could also say Groovy 2.3 proposes traits, Scala also does.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutGroup1 and LayoutGroup2 can both extend one class with doSpecialLayout() method.
You can also create interface and define method doSpecialLayout(), but then u need to implement method in all clasess implementing this interface.

Comment: In Java 8 you have interfaces with default methods.

Comment: Nice, similar to groovy trait.

Comment: I can certainly use an interface to ensure each class that shares this common logic implements it.  I was just hoping to have this logic in ONE place.

Comment: As Michał Urbaniak mentioned, use default method and do not override it in implementing classes.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutGroup2 and LayoutGroup1 can extend from another class that have the method  doSpecialLayout()
so create a new class, implements the method there, and extend in your  LayoutGroup classes from that one

Comment: Sure, that'd be simple.  But LayoutGroup1 extends SpecialLayout1 for example, and LayoutGroup2 extends SpecialLayout2.  So there is a difference in their parent classes that are being extended... so this won't work unfortunately.

Comment: so don´t thing more in extends, create a class with some commons methos like doSpecialLayout()  also can be with singleton pattern and create an instance where do you need

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern. It makes possible to dynamically create classes with various methods/behaviours you want to include.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your common code in static method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Strategy Pattern.

This pattern uses composition instead of inheritance.

So you create a new class lets say `SpecialLayoutBehaviour` which extends a LayoutBehaviour

```
public interface LayoutBehaviour {
    void doLayout()
}

public class SpecialLayoutBehaviour extends LayoutBehaviour {
    public void doLayout() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Then in your LayoutGroup1 and LayoutGroup2 classes:

```
public interface LayoutGroup {
    void doLayoutBehaviour();
}

public abstract class LayoutGroup1 implements LayoutGroup {
    void doLayoutBehaviour();
}

public class Layout1 extends LayoutGroup1 {
    private LayoutBehaviour behaviour;

    public Layout1 () {
        behaviour = new SpecialLayoutBehaviour();
    }

    public void doLayoutBehaviour() {
        behaviour.doLayout();
    }
}
```

Then do the same for layout2, ie get LayoutGroup2 to also implement LayoutGroup

E.g.

```
public abstract class LayoutGroup2 implements LayoutGroup {
    void doLayoutBehaviour();
}

public class Layout2 extends LayoutGroup2 {
    private LayoutBehaviour behaviour;

    public Layout2 () {
        behaviour = new SpecialLayoutBehaviour();
    }

    public void doLayoutBehaviour() {
        behaviour.doLayout();
    }
}
```

Now the LayoutGroupX class can have whatever code is required and they will share the spoecial layout behaviour.

This also allows you to create layouts that have different special layout behaviour. 
E.g. Let's say layout3 uses `boringLayoutBehaviour`:

```
public abstract class LayoutGroup3 implements LayoutGroup {
    void doLayoutBehaviour();
}

public class Layout3 extends LayoutGroup2 {
    private LayoutBehaviour behaviour;

    public Layout3 () {
        behaviour = new BoringLayoutBehaviour();
    }

    public void doLayoutBehaviour() {
        behaviour.doLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java8 and interface with default method

```
public interface LayoutGroupInterface {
    default void doSpecialLayout(){
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Layout1 extends LayoutGroup1 implements LayoutGroupInterface
```

Check [this blog](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/) for some examples

Answer (score 0):

Check "[Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)" paradigm. In you case you can create third class `SpecialLayout` that will have method `doSpecialLayout()`. Then include instances of this class into your `LayoutGroup1` and `Layout2` call `doSpecialLayout()` where you need it.

Additionally, if you want method `doSpecialLayout()` to be public (part of public API), you have to create separate interface that will have this method. `LayoutGroup1` and `Layout2` can then implement that interface and delegate calls of `doSpecialLayout()` to internal instance of `SpecialLayout`.